# How to change all values in this nested list?

Tags: python

The function `gboard` is suppose to return a nested list in column major order. I have gotten it to do this, but I am not sure of how to set each value in the list equal to 0 (or the variable I set equal to 0 in another function called `constants.dead`.) If anyone has any idea of how I could do this I would appreciate the help.

```py
def gboard(height, width):
    """ Returns: Nested list in column-major order representing a game board.  All the cells in the board are in the set to 0.

    Parameter height: number of rows in the board
    Parameter width: number of columns in the board
    Precondition: height and width are positive ints
    """
    list = []
    for y in range(width):
        list.append([])
        for x in range(height):
            list[y].append(x)
    return list
```

The output of the function for example is this:

```py
>>> gboard(4,3)
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

But I would rather it be:

```py
>>> gboard(4,3)
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: my suggestion: `board = [width*[0] for _ in range(height)]`, and please do nut use `list` as variable name...

Comment: ah okay i wont use ```list``` but i am still confused as to what ```board``` is for you and where you get 19 from.

Comment: that would be the return value of your function... `return board`, ...added as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you use a list-comprehesion:

```
def gboard(height, width):
     return [height*[0] for _ in range(width)]
```

that would produce

```
gboard(4, 3) 
# [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

change `list[y].append(x)` to `list[y].append(0)`

strange it didn't worked for you. apparently this code worked for me:

```
def gboard(height, width):
    """ Returns: Nested list in column-major order representing a game board.  All the cells in the board are in the set to 0.

    Parameter height: number of rows in the board
    Parameter width: number of columns in the board
    Precondition: height and width are positive ints
    """
    list = []
    for y in range(width):
        list.append([])
        for x in range(height):
            list[y].append(0)
    return list
  
print(gboard(4, 3))
```

output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried this and it does not work I get a Type Error: ```TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (0 given)``` And this happens if i put anything within those parentheses besides x. (any int value)